# Flink DataStream API with Predicate type logic

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-sql

I want to write a Flink Streaming application that uses the DataStream API. I would like to do something similar to what KStream offers.

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

`dataStream.map(...).filter(new CustomPredicateFilterFunction<>()).toSink();`

The `CustomPredicateFilterFunction` takes in a `Predicate` type as input. The `Predicate` is basically an Expression tree that is traversed through and the filter condition is decided.

Is this possible? I want to use a SQL Parser and customize it to behave this way. Would this make sense or should I just use Flink SQL?

Comment: Is the predicate static, or are you expecting to update it while the application is running?

Comment: Yes, we expect the predicate to change (not very frequently though).

Answer (score 1):

With Flink SQL, modifying the query will entail recompiling and restarting the job. What you propose is feasible, but it seems like a lot of effort to avoid a bit of downtime.